# PHP Composer Repo push Jenkins Trigger

Tags: php, git, magento, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a `composer.json` file which contains a number of dependencies as Git repositories. I have a Jenkins server running on AWS. Now what I actually want is to trigger Jenkins Pipeline whenever a pull request is merged in any of those dependencies defined in `composer.json` file.

Should I have to create a trigger in each repo's settings or is there a better way? Suggestions will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Do all the repositories belong to you or are 3rd party?

Comment: All the repositories are part of the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Jenkins to trigger. Everytime a submodule or package is changed via SCM, you trigger after the build the main project.

- Every repository has its own jenkins job.
- Each has an SCM trigger and listens to changes.
- Every job in the composer.json - not the main project - has a downstrem post build trigger to run the main project job.
- when the main project is triggered it runs composer update to get all new versions and runs itself with the new lib version

Comment: You mean, you would configure Jenkins to check for updated modules periodically, right?

Comment: via SCM change trigger  every minute

Comment: But how does it will look for change through all the repositories and trigger the build?

Comment: It does not look for changes in all reps. Every rep looks for itself an tells the main project. 
1. You change a  lib you use in your main project.
2. Jenkins hears on SCM change and runs
3. Jenkins triggers main job
4. main jobs runs composer update and starts job with the new lib

Comment: That's sounds good. So proably if main project is updated through a sub-repo in `composer.json` file, we can also setup a Jenkins trigger there too. But how do every repo will tell the main project if one of them changes?

Comment: Just start the job with a jenkins post build trigger

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more by updating your answer? Just need elaboration a bit. Thanks